# CORS erro ao usar fetch API js - destino origem

Tags: javascript, java, cors

Bom, estou tentando usar Js puro e html, para consumir uma api, rodando no localhost. Segue os códigos:
Java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JavaScript(rodando em um servidor local)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém ele retorna um erro de cors, sendo que eu estou colocando origem e destino no header de destino, e no header de retorno. Quando não uso cors, funciona, porém ele não me retorna o body. Quando habilito o cors, ele retorna o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido com uma simples anotação, no lado do backend:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]